# Euler-Bernoulli equation for beams

Tags: waves

How can I identify the waves velocity formula of an Euler Bernoulli equation? Is it c = Young's modulus over density ratio?

Comment: This question is for application to transverse vibration of beams

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Can you add more detail to your question? As it stands (v1) it's unclear.

Comment: Please see the following answer from Mike Stone, who has clearly understood and answered my question. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ernesto, notice Mike says explicitly that he had "assume" what you wanted. If people have to guess what you want it's a good sign the question could be clearer. But glad it served you - don't forget to upvote any answer that's helpful and accept Mike's answer since, as you say, it's exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Stafusa please let me know how to upvote for Mike's answer is accepted by me

Comment: You can upvote by clicking in the up arrow close to the number of votes the post has (currently 0), but, just realized now: you need at least 15 reputation points to be able to do that, check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369732). But you *should* be able to **accept** his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to solve 
$$
YI \frac{\partial^4 y}{\partial x^4}+ \rho\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} =0
$$ 
where $Y$ is young's modulus $I$ the appropriate second moment of area, and $\rho$ the mass per unit length.  You subsititute 
$$
y= e^{i(kx-\omega t)}
$$
to see that $\sqrt{YI/\rho}\times  k^2 =  \omega$. Thus the phase velocity of transverese waves is
$$
v_{\rm phase}\equiv \omega/k = \sqrt{YI/\rho}\times k
$$ 
and is strongly dependent on the wavelength $2\pi/k$ . There is no single wave velocity "$c$". The group velocity  is
$$
v_{\rm group}\equiv  \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}= 2\sqrt{YI/\rho}\times k 
$$
and is twice as fast as the phase velocity. Consequently the wavecrests will move backwards when viewed from the  the centre of a wave pulse.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your clear answer. It's exactly what I was looking for.